# Populate Android ListView with files

Tags: android

How to populate a ListView with directory and files from memory card in android.
Please recommend some links or books.

Comment: what u have tried so far?

Comment: This has been asked and implemented for n! times. (n approaching +inf)

Answer (score 3):

Try this page: http://android-er.blogspot.hu/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html

Copied the code, if the link would dead in the future:

Row.xml

```
<TextView 

  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:id="@+id/rowtext"

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"

     android:layout_height="25px"

     android:textSize="23sp" />
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >

<TextView

 android:id="@+id/path"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    />

<ListView

 android:id="@android:id/list"

 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

 />

<TextView

 android:id="@android:id/empty"

 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    android:text="No Data"

 />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidExplorer.java:

```
package com.AndroidExplorer;



import java.io.File;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.TextView;



public class AndroidExplorer extends ListActivity {



 private List<String> item = null;

 private List<String> path = null;

 private String root="/";

 private TextView myPath;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

        getDir(root);

    }



    private void getDir(String dirPath)

    {

     myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);



     item = new ArrayList<String>();

     path = new ArrayList<String>();



     File f = new File(dirPath);

     File[] files = f.listFiles();



     if(!dirPath.equals(root))

     {



      item.add(root);

      path.add(root);



      item.add("../");

      path.add(f.getParent());



     }



     for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)

     {

       File file = files[i];

       path.add(file.getPath());

       if(file.isDirectory())

        item.add(file.getName() + "/");

       else

        item.add(file.getName());

     }



     ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =

      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, item);

     setListAdapter(fileList);

    }



 @Override

 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {



  File file = new File(path.get(position));



  if (file.isDirectory())

  {

   if(file.canRead())

    getDir(path.get(position));

   else

   {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)

    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")

    .setPositiveButton("OK", 

      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {



       @Override

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

      }).show();

   }

  }

  else

  {

   new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)

    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")

    .setPositiveButton("OK", 

      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {



       @Override

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

      }).show();

  }

 }

}
```

Comment: Damn! You beat me with the same link by a few seconds! +1 For copying code in case link goes down.

Comment: Sorry for that :P BTW it is a very good example and blog!

Answer (score 1):

You could have just done a quick google search. [Here](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-simple-file-explore-in-android.html) is step-by-step tutorial to do that.

Comment: A bundle of thanks..!!!
This is what i need...

Comment: you can help me by up-voting and marking it correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html) link:

Use `java.io.File` classes to read files from directory:

```
String dirPath = "some directory full path goes here";
File f = new File(dirPath);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

Then you can complete your tutorial in same link which lists files in `ListView`.

For another quick link on `ListView` populating, you can try [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

---

**EDIT:**

If you're new to Android (and from your post you may as well be), try a couple of [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/) from [Lars Vogel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272641/lars-vogel). They are well written and easy to understand.